# MYSQL: selecting id with maximum integer value in another field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have mysql table which has 2 fields as below:

```
id      item_id
49822   16667
49898   16693
49899   16693
49900   16693
53735   17972
53736   17972
53737   17972
```

In the table `id` is `PK` and `item_id` is another field.

I want to select the `id` values with `max(item_id)` In other words, output should look like as below

```
id      item_id
53735   17972
53736   17972
53737   17972
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE item_id = (SELECT max(item_id) FROM YourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get this by self join also

```
select a.*
from demo a
left join demo b on a.item_id < b.item_id
where b.item_id is null
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/ARK80782)